# Group acting on locally finite tree

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, self-learning

Let $G$ be a group acting on a locally finite connected tree $T$ i.e. each vertex degree is finite. Let $G$ has compact open topology i.e. for each compact set $C$ and an open set $U$ of $T$, the sets $\{f\in G\colon f(C)\subseteq U\}$ form a subbasis of this topology (see Topology and Geometry-Bredon). Prove that $G$ is locally compact. Can we replace tree by arbitrary graph?

**Edit:** (T.B.) This question is closely related to (but **not** a duplicate of) [Automorphism Group of a graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49359/).

Comment: Two things: First, you certainly want to assume that no element of $G$ acts trivially (the elements fixing everything are not separated by the compact open topology as you define it). So $G$ *embeds* into the automorphism group. Second: consider the graph equipped with its length metric (shortest length of a path connecting two points). Then $G$ acts by isometries, since $G$ acts by graph automorphisms. But a sequence of isometries converges uniformly on compact sets if and only if it converges pointwise (because isometries are Lipschitz)

Comment: @Theo: In the paper "Topological Groups and infinite graphs" suggested in the answer of similar question, the author assumes that the group is acting transitively on vertices of tree; it is needed in the proof of the LEMMA 1. But here in question, I have considered only action of group $G$, not necessarily transitive.

Comment: @all 3k+ users: I **retract** my earlier close vote and **vote against closing**. I would appreciate it if *future* close votes would be accompanied by a comment with a ping at me explaining why it should be an exact duplicate. It's not; [Pete's answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49359/automorphism-group-of-a-graph/49444#49444) and the article linked therein don't really answer the present question (I wouldn't have written such an elaborate answer here).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you asked in a comment about the compact open topology. I recommend that you read the extraordinarily good exposition in Chapter XII in Dugundji's *[Topology](http://books.google.com/books?id=FgFRAAAAMAAJ)*, Allyn and Bacon, 1966. Most other books on general topology contain discussions of that as well, e.g. [Munkres](http://books.google.com/books?id=XjoZAQAAIAAJ), §46. The actual question is discussed in the next part of the answer. I'd also recommend to read [Pete's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49359/automorphism-group-of-a-graph/49444#49444) in the related question first before reading here. People acquainted with the compact open topology can safely scroll down to the displayed **Conclusion** and read from there on.

---

So let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary topological spaces. Consider the set of continuous functions $C(X,Y)$ equipped with the compact open topology, i.e., the topology generated by the subbasis

$$O_{K,U} = \{f \in C(X,Y)\,:\,f(K) \subset U\} \qquad K \subset X \text{ compact, } U \subset Y \text{ open.} $$

It is often helpful to think of open sets in a topological space as consisting of points that are near to each other. This topology is inspired by this. More precisely, let $f$ be a continuous function then $f$ maps the compact set $K$ to a compact set $f(K) \subset Y$. Fixing a "small" neighborhood $U$ of $f(K)$ we consider a function $g$ as *near* to $f$ if $g(K) \subset U$ as well. By taking $K$ "very large in $X$" and $U$ a "very small neighborhood" of $f(K)$ then $g$ will be quite close to $f$, intuitively. By cutting up our "large" $K$ into finitely many very small pieces $K_{1}, \ldots, K_n$ and taking tiny neighborhoods $U_i$ of $f(K_i)$ then a $g \in O_{K_1,U_1} \cap \cdots \cap O_{K_n,U_n}$ will be forced to be extremely close to $f$ on all of $K$.

This can be made precise e.g. by the following observation:

> Let $(Y,d)$ be a *metric* space. Then a sequence $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the compact-open topology if and only if $f_n \to f$ *uniformly on compact sets*: for every compact $K \subset X$ we have $$d_{K}(f,f_n) = \sup_{x \in K}{\;d(f(x),f_n(x))}\;\xrightarrow{n \to \infty}\;0.$$

You can find the proof of this in Dugundji, Proposition 7.2, p. 268. However, I recommend that you prove this on your own to get a certain familiarity with the compact-open topology.

Note that we have a *means* of quantifying closeness if $Y$ is metric: two points are $\varepsilon$-close if their distance is less than $\varepsilon$ and two functions $f,g$ are $\varepsilon$-close (relative $K$) if $d_{K}(f,g) \lt \varepsilon$, that is *all* values of all $x \in K$ are $\varepsilon$-close.

Next, we have the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem (in one of its many incarnations). Recall that a metric space $(Y,d)$ is called *proper* if all closed balls are compact. Metric spaces with this condition are sometimes also called metric spaces with the Heine-Borel property (closed and bounded sets are compact).

> Let $X$ be an arbitrary space and let $Y$ be a proper metric space. Let $\mathscr{F} \subset C(X,Y)$ be a family of functions. Then $\mathscr{F}$ is relatively compact in the compact-open topology if and only if
>
> 1. The family $\mathscr{F}$ is pointwise bounded: for all $x \in X$ the set $\{f(x)\,:\,f \in \mathscr{F}\}$ is bounded.
> 2. The family $\mathscr{F}$ is [equicontinuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity).

To relate the present answer to the [paper by Woess](http://www.math.tugraz.at/~woess/papers/top-graphs.pdf) mentioned by Pete in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49359/automorphism-group-of-a-graph/49444#49444) to a related question, you'll need the following simple observation whose proof I leave to you:

> Let $f_n$ be an equicontinuous family of functions. Then $f_n \to f$ pointwise if and only if $f_n \to f$ uniformly on compact sets.

The upshot of this long-winded preliminary discussion is:

> **Conclusion** Let $(X,d)$ be a proper metric space, i.e., closed balls are compact. Let $G = \operatorname{Isom}{(X)}$ be the group of isometries, equipped with the compact-open topology. Then $G$ is a locally compact topological group, the action $G \times X \to X$ is continuous and the action is proper (in particular stabilizers of points are compact, orbits are closed and $X/G$ is Hausdorff—even metrizable).

*Proof.* Rather immediate:

1. *Local compactness.* Let $g \in G$, let $x_0 \in X$ be an arbitrary point and $\varepsilon \gt 0$. Put $K = \{x_0\}$ and $U = B_{\varepsilon}(gx_0)$ then $\mathscr{F} = O_{K,U}$ is relatively compact. 
    Indeed, if $h \in \mathscr{F}$ and $x \in X$ is arbitrary then $$d(gx_{0},hx) \leq d(gx_0, hx_0) + d(hx_0,hx) \leq \varepsilon +  d(x_0,x),$$
   so $\mathscr{F}$ is pointwise bounded. Since isometries are $1$-Lipschitz, $\mathscr{F}$ is equicontinuous and it follows from Arzelà–Ascoli that $\mathscr{F}$ is relatively compact. But this means that every point in $G$ has a compact neighborhood.
2. The group operations are continuous, hence $G$ is a topological group.
3. *Continuity of the action.* Exercise (use that $g_n \to g$ means uniform convergence on compact sets and that closed balls  in $X$ are compact).
4. The verification of [properness of the action](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55726/) is straightforward and the rest follows from generalities on proper actions (see my answer on MO).

---

Let $\Gamma$ be a *connected* locally finite graph and equip it (or rather its geometric realization) with the length metric: edges are isometric to the unit interval and the distance between two points on $\Gamma$ is the infimum over all lengths of paths connecting them. This gives a metric on the graph inducing the correct (locally compact) topology on $\Gamma$ — note that closed balls are compact in this topology since $\Gamma$ is locally finite and connected. So $\Gamma$ is proper and we may apply the results from the first part of the answer.

It is plain that a graph automorphism maps paths to paths, so the automorphism group of $\Gamma$ can then be identified with a closed subgroup of the isometry group of $\Gamma$. We equip $\operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)$ with the compact open topology. Combining the facts above we see:

1. Every $g \in \operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)$ has a compact neighborhood. 
    Indeed, take any point $x_{0} \in \Gamma$ and let $K= \{x_{0}\}$ and let $U = B_{\varepsilon}(g(x))$. Then $O_{K,U}$ is relatively compact by Arzelà-Ascoli: Indeed, $O_{K,U}$ is equicontinuous since all elements are isometries (hence $1$-Lipschitz), so condition 2. is satisfied; condition 1. is satisfied because for any point $x \in X$ and $h \in O_{K,U}$ we have $d(gx_{0},hx) \leq d(gx_0, hx_0) + d(hx_0,hx) \leq \varepsilon +  d(x_0,x).$
2. If $G$ is a group acting on $\Gamma$ by graph automorphisms let $N$ be the normal subgroup consisting of the elements acting trivially, then $G/N$ is a group acting on the graph $\Gamma$. There are two problems in the statement you ask about:

   - The compact open topology, as you define it endows $N$ with the trivial topology, in particular $G$ is not Hausdorff if $N$ is non-trivial. Since $N$ is not interesting anyway, I wouldn't take the pains and worry about it:  simply throw it away and consider $G/N$ instead of $G$.
      But then a further unpleasant surprise awaits us:
   - The image of $G/N$ in $\operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)$ **need not** be closed — but the compact open topology *is* the relative topology of $G/N$ as a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)$. 
      However, one can show that a locally compact subgroup of a Hausdorff group **is** closed, see e.g. [Corollary 5.11 on p.35](http://books.google.com/books?id=uf11K1wXEYUC&pg=PA35) of Hewitt–Ross, *[Abstract Harmonic Analysis I](http://books.google.com/books?id=uf11K1wXEYUC)*, so we're in trouble and 
     this *is* a serious problem: 
     Since $\operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)$ is only rarely discrete for homogeneous enough graphs (e.g. complete $n$-ary trees) there will be plenty of non-closed subgroups (take a countable dense subset $D$ of any closed subgroup and consider the subgroup $\langle D \rangle$ generated by it, for example). 
     So you need a condition **ensuring** that $G/N$ is a closed subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)$. Off the top of my head I can't think of any such condition.
3. Finally, *if* $G/N$ is locally compact (i.e., closed in $\operatorname{Aut}(\Gamma)$) and $G$ is equipped with the compact-open topology then $G$ is locally compact as an extension of the locally compact group $G/N$ by the (locally) compact group $N$ by [Theorem 5.25 on p.39](http://books.google.com/books?id=uf11K1wXEYUC&pg=PA39) of Hewitt-Ross, (provided that you check that the compact-open topology indeed defines a group topology on $G$, which I haven't done but I'm not too worried about).

I think that's the best I can do at the moment without further information on what you actually want to do.

---

**Edit:** As a further remark (as Pete notes in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49359/automorphism-group-of-a-graph/49444#49444)) the above extends easily to graphs with finitely many connected components, but can fail with infinitely many connected components, as already the trivial graph on a countable set shows.

Comment: Thanks! Transparent Answer!!