# Compact metric space group $\operatorname{Iso}(X,d)$ is also compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Could you tell me how to prove that if metric space $(X,d)$ is compact, then the group $\operatorname{Iso}(X,d)$ is also compact?

The group $\operatorname{Iso}(X,d)$ is considered with topology determined by a metric $\rho$ on $\operatorname{Iso}(X,d)$ such that
$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \rho(h_n, h) =0 \iff \forall x \in X: \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} d(h_n(x), h(x))=0$

Comment: Under which topology are you considering $\text{Iso}(X,d)$?

Comment: If it is the topology of pointwise convergence, then $Iso(X,d)$ is closed in $X^X$ which is compact by Tychonoff.

Comment: @julien: the topology as presented in the post seems to be of pointwise convergent (however the notion of $\rho$ is a bit shadowy), so you are probably right.

Comment: Why is $Iso(X,d)$ closed in $X^X$?

Comment: @Sandy : as $X$ is compact, $f\in Iso(X,d)$ if and only if $\forall x, y, d(x,y) = d(f(x),f(y))$ (injectivity clearly follows, as usual, and surjectivity follows by standard compactness arguments if I'm not mistaken) This is a closed condition, and so $Iso(X,d)$ is closed. However I don't think it's true that for a metric space $X$, $Iso(X,d)$ is closed in $X^X$ (so your question was important !)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the precise definition of the metric $\rho$, I'm not sure how to answer this definitively, but let me outline an approach that you might be able to take. For this approach, I take as a hidden assumption that the Principle of Dependent Choices holds, so to show that $Y:=\text{Iso}(X,d)$ is compact (considered as a metric space with metric $\rho$), it suffices to show that it is complete and totally bounded.

To show that $\langle Y,\rho\rangle$ is a complete metric space, suppose that we have a $\rho$-Cauchy sequence of functions $h_n\in Y.$ Show that for each $x\in X,$ we have that $h_n(x)$ is a $d$-Cauchy sequence of points of $X$. Since $X$ is a compact space under the $d$-metric topology, then it is complete, so $h_n(x)$ converges in $X$. Define $h:X\to X$ by $h(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}h_n(x).$ Show that $h\in Y,$ and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\rho(h_n,h)=0,$ so $\langle Y,\rho\rangle$ is a complete metric space.

To show that $\langle Y,\rho\rangle$ is a totally bounded metric space, we must show that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $f_1,...,f_n\in Y$ such that $Y$ is covered by the open $\rho$-balls about $f_1,...,f_n$ of radius $\epsilon$. Without a definition for $\rho,$ I'm afraid I have no suggestions for how to proceed with this.

---

**Edit**: If julien is correct in his comment above, that you're simply considering $Y$ in the topology of pointwise convergence (which, in retrospect, it seems that you are), then I'm not certain that it's necessarily induced by a metric. Fortunately, we can proceed without worrying about such a metric.

Let's proceed as follows, instead. Denote the set of all functions $X\to X$ by $X^X$. Given a point $x\in X$ and an open set $U$ in $X,$ we define $$P(x,U):=\{f\in X^X:f(x)\in U\},$$ and let $\mathcal B$ be the set of all sets of the form $$P(x_1,B_1)\cap\cdots\cap P(x_k,B_k)$$ for some positive integer $k$, with the $x_j\in X$ and the $B_j$ open balls in $X$. You can show that $\mathcal B$ is a basis for a topology on $X^X$, say $\mathcal T$, which is the set of unions of $\mathcal B$-sets. We call $\mathcal T$ the *topology of pointwise convergence*, because of the following

> **Lemma**: If $h_n$ is a sequence of functions $X\to X$ and $h:X\to X$, then $h_n\to h$ with respect to the topology $\mathcal T$ if and only if $h_n(x)\to h(x)$ for each $x\in X$.
>
> **Proof**: Suppose $h_n(x)\to h(x)$ for all $x\in X$, and take any $\mathcal B$-basic neighborhood of $h$, which will be of the form $$P(x_1,B_1)\cap\cdots\cap P(x_k,B_k)$$ for some $x_j\in X$ and some open balls $B_j$ with $h(x_j)\in B_j$. Since $h_n(x_j)\to h(x_j)$, then there exists $n_j$ such that $h_n(x_j)\in B_j$ for $n\ge n_j$. Putting $N=\max\{n_1,...,n_k\}$, we therefore have for $n\ge N$ that $$h_n\in P(x_1,B_1)\cap\cdots\cap P(x_k,B_k).$$ Thus, $h_n\to h$ with respect to $\mathcal T$.
>
> On the other hand, suppose that $h_n\to h$ with respect to $\mathcal T$. Take any $x\in X$ and any open ball $B$ in $X$ such that $h(x)\in B$. Since $P(x,B)$ is a $\mathcal T$-neighborhood of $h$ and $h_n\to h$, then there is some $N$ such that $h_n\in P(x,B)$ for $n\ge N$, meaning $h_n(x)\in B$ for all $n\ge N$. Thus, $h_n(x)\to h(x)$ for all $x\in X$. $\Box$

Now, julien refers to Tychonoff Theorem (a very useful theorem that requires the Axiom of Choice to prove) in his comment above. We really only need the following special case:

> **Theorem**: $X^X$ is compact in the topology of pointwise convergence if (and only if) $X$ is compact.

The "only if" part is fairly easy to prove, and if you're interested, I can prove the other direction (though it can be a bit of a bear to prove without just using another form of the Tychonoff Theorem).

Hence, all that is left for you to do is to show that $Y$ is a *closed* subspace of $X^X$, from which the result follows.

Comment: The topology of pointwise convergence on the group of isometries on a metric space is the same as uniform convergence (on compact sets) and that *is* metric (observe that isometries are uniformly Lipschitz). So, you could also apply Arzela-Ascoli.

Comment: @Martin Your comment shouldn't be buried here. Would you make that an answer? Also, it is metric if there exists a compact exhaustion of the space on which the isometries act. Still the case if no such exhaustion exists? If it is separable, I see that. But otherwise...

Comment: @julien: what do you mean by exhaustion?

Comment: @DamianSobota Compact exhaustion of $X$ means $X=\bigcup_{n\geq 1} K_n$ with every $K_n$ compact and $(K_n)$ generally required to be nondecreasing.

Comment: Is there really a significant simplification in the argument $X$ compact implies $X^X$ compact as opposed to the general Tychonoff $X^Y$ compact?

Comment: @julien: I was having an implicit "closed balls are compact" assumption in mind which I forgot to write. OP only asks about the compact case anyway. I only intended this to be a small addendum to Cameron's long answer expressing doubt about metrizability and adding this trivial point as a standalone answer doesn't feel right. I wouldn't have much to say that isn't covered in the long answer [in this old thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59625/) anyway.

Comment: @julien: I thought there was when I originally posted this, but now I'm not quite sure. I know how to prove it if the Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem holds (since this is equivalent to products of compact Hausdorff spaces being compact Hausdorff), and I suspect that this special case may be provable without even *that* much Choice, but I'm still working on it. It was a good excuse to gain a better understanding of compactness, anyway. ;-)

Comment: @Martin: Thank you for your comment. Let me make certain I understand you correctly. Are you saying that the topology on $\text{Iso}(X,d)$ is the same whether we consider it as a subspace of $X^X$ in the pointwise convergence topology or as a subspace of $X^X$ in the uniform topology?

Comment: Yes (if $X$ is compact). The point is that pointwise convergence of an *equicontinuous* sequence (or net) of functions implies its local uniform convergence. Compactness then allows you to improve this to uniform convergence.

Comment: @Martin: Once again, thank you. I'll work up a proof of that and adapt my answer accordingly when I have a chance to sit down (with acknowledgment of your excellent assistance).

Comment: If it is too much work for you, I can expand on my comments in a separate answer. Let me know if you want me to do so.

Comment: @Martin: Could you expand on your comment in a separate answer?

Answer (score 6):

Yesterday I was involved in this thread. Hoping to clarify some claims, I have some
things to say so I decided to create a new answer instead of writing of big comments.

I shall use the following notations. Put $Y=\operatorname{Iso}(X,d)$. I consider the following
three topologies defined on the set $Y$: the topology $\tau_u$ of the uniform convergence,
the topology $\tau_p$ of the pointwise convergence, and the topology $\tau_\rho,$
determined by the metric $\rho$.

I should remark that the condition
$$(*) \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \rho(h_n, h) =0 \iff \forall x \in X: \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} d(h_n(x),
h(x))=0,$$
is not a definition of the metric $\rho$, it is a property of the metric. So there arise a
question: "how the topologies $\tau_u$, $\tau_p$, and $\tau_\rho$ on the set $Y$ are related?",
which I shall answer in my answer. :-)

@Cameron Buie wrote:

> To show that $\langle Y,\rho\rangle$ is a complete metric space, suppose that we
>   have a $\rho$-Cauchy sequence of functions $h_n\in Y.$ Show that for each $x\in X,$ we have
>   that $h_n(x)$ is a $d$-Cauchy sequence of points of $X$. Since $X$ is a compact space under
>   the $d$-metric topology, then it is complete, so $h_n(x)$ converges in $X$.
>   Define $h:X\to X$ by $h(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}h_n(x).$ Show that $h\in Y,$ and that
>   $\lim_{n\to\infty}\rho(h_n,h)=0,$ so $\langle Y,\rho\rangle$ is a complete metric space.

For me it was easier to show these claims in the opposite order, :-) see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409087/prove-that-there-exists-a-cauchy-sequence-compact-metric-space-topology-of-poi?lq=1).

---

@Sandy wrote:

> Why is $Iso(X,d)$  closed in $X^X$?

Suppose that a map $h$ is contained in the set $X^X\backslash Y$. I am going to
find an open neighborhood $U$ of the map $h$ (in the topology of pointwise convergence on $X^X$),
such that the intersection $U\cap Y$ is empty. At first I suppose that the map $h$
is not isometric of the space $(X,d)$. Then there exist points $x,y\in X$ such that
$d(h(x),h(y))\not=d(x,y)$. Then it suffices to put $\varepsilon=|d(h(x),h(y))-d(x,y)|$ and
$U=\{g\in X^X: d(g(x),h(x))<\varepsilon/2$ and $d(g(y),h(y))<\varepsilon/2\}$.
If the map $h$ is isometric, but $h$ is still in $X^X\backslash Y$, then the map
$h$ is not surjective. Therefore there exists a point $x\in X\backslash h(X)$. Fix a number
$\varepsilon>0$ such that $\varepsilon<d(x,h(X))$. Since $X$ is a metric compact,
there exists a finite $\varepsilon/2$-net $F$ of  $X$, that is $F$ is a finite subset of
$X$ such that for any point $y\in X$ there exists a point $z\in F$ such that $d(x,z)<\varepsilon/2$.
 Put $U=\{g\in X^X: (\forall z\in F)(d(g(z),h(z))<\varepsilon/2)\}$.
Suppose that there exists a map $g\in U\cap Y$. Put $y=g^{-1}(x)$.
Since the set $F$ is a $\varepsilon/2$-net $F$ of  $X$, there exists a point
$z\in F$ such that $d(y,z)<\varepsilon/2$. Since the map $g$ is an isometry of the space
$(X,d)$, I have that $d(g(y),g(z))=d(y,z)<\varepsilon/2$. But then
$d(x, h(z))=d(g(y),h(z)) \le d(g(y),g(z))+$ $d(g(z),h(z))< \varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2=\varepsilon$,
a contradiction.

Therefore the space $(Y,\tau_p)$ is compact.

Now I show that the topologies $\tau_u$ and $\tau_p$ coincide. The inclusion $\tau_p\subset\tau_u$
is obvious, so it rests to prove the opposite inclusion.
Let $h\in Y$ and $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. I am going to
find an open neighborhood $U\in\tau_p$ of the map $h$
such that $d(g(x),h(x))<\varepsilon$ for each map $g\in U$ and each point $x\in X$.
Since $X$ is a metric compact,
there exists a finite $\varepsilon/3$-net $F$ of $X$.
Put $U=\{g\in Y: (\forall z\in F)(d(g(z),h(z))<\varepsilon/3)\}$.
Let $g\in U$ and $x\in X$ be arbitrary.
Since the set $F$ is a $\varepsilon/3$-net $F$ of  $X$, there exists a point
$z\in F$ such that $d(x,z)<\varepsilon/3$.
Since the maps $g$ and $h$ are isometries of the space
$(X,d)$, I have that $d(g(x),h(x))\le d(g(x),g(z))+d(g(z),h(z))+$ $d(h(z),h(x))=
d(x,z)+d(g(z),h(z))+d(z,x)<\varepsilon/3+\varepsilon/3+\varepsilon/3=\varepsilon.$

Hence, $\tau_u=\tau_p$.

How I show that $\tau_\rho\subset\tau_u$. Suppose the opposite. Then there exist a point
$h\in Y$ and a number $\varepsilon>0$ such that for each natural number there is a
point $h_n\in Y$ such that $d(h_n(x),h(x))<1/n$ for each $x\in X$,
but $\rho(h_n,h)\ge\varepsilon$. Then a sequence $\{h_n\}$ uniformly
converges to $h$. Then property (*) implies that $\rho(h_n,h)$ converges to $0$,
contradicting the inequality $\rho(h_n,h)\ge\varepsilon$.

Since the space $(Y,\tau_u)$ is compact and $\tau_\rho$ is a Hausdorff topology on $Y$
weaker than $\tau_u$ then $\tau_\rho=\tau_u$, by well-known Theorem 3.1.10 from [Eng].

---

@julien wrote

> it is metric if there exists a compact exhaustion of the space on which the
>   isometries act. Still the case if no such exhaustion exists? If it is separable,
>   I see that. But otherwise...

... there should be a counterexample. Let $X$ be an uncountable set endowed with a metric
$d$ such that $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=1$ in the opposite case. Then $\operatorname{Iso(X,d)}$
is a group $S(X)$ of all bijections of the set $X$. The group $S(X)$ endowed
with the pointwise topology has a base $\{[A]:A$ is a finite subset of $X\}$, where
$[A]=\{g:\in S(X):(\forall x\in A)g(x)=x\}$. Therefore this topological group
should be not metrizable (even not a first countable).

At last I allow myself to cite the beginning of a recent paper [BGP] by my scientific consultant
Taras Banakh, my scientific adviser Igor Guran, and well known in Ukrainian circles of topological algebra
Igor Protasov: "In this paper we answer several problems of Dikran Dikranjan concerning
 algebraically determined
topologies on the group $S(X)$ of permutations of a set $X$.$\dots$ The symmetric group $S(X)$
carries a natural group topology, namely the topology of
pointwise convergence $\tau_p$, inherited from the Tychonoff power $X^X$ of the set $X$
endowed with the discrete topology.$\dots$ Answering a question of Ulam [Sco, p.178](cf. [Ula]),
Gaughan [Gau] proved
that for each set $X$ the topology $\tau_p$ is the coarsest Hausdorff group topology on the
symmetric group $G=S(X)$ (cf. [DPS, 1.7.9] and [Dik, 5.2.2])".

**References**

[BGP] Taras Banakh, Igor Guran, Igor Protasov. *[Algebraically determined topologies on permutation
groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0087)*, Topology Appl. **159**:9 (2012) 2258-2268

[Dik] D. Dikranjan, *[Introduction to topological groups](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/~dikran.dikranjan/ITG.pdf)*,
(book in progress).

[DPS] D. Dikranjan, I. Prodanov, L. Stoyanov, *Topological groups.
Characters, dualities and minimal group topologies*, Marcel Dekker, Inc., New York, 1990.

[Eng] Ryszard Engelking. *General Topology* (Russian version, 1986).

[Gau] E. Gaughan, *Group structures of infinite symmetric groups*,
Proc. Nat. Acad. Sci. U.S.A. **58** (1967), 907-910.

[Sco] D. Mauldin (ed.), *The Scottish Book. Mathematics from the Scottish Caf\'e*,
Birkhauser, Boston, Mass., 1981.

[Ulam] S. Ulam, *A Collection of Mathematical Problems*, Intersci. Publ., NY, 1960.