# Compactness of the set of surjective isometries between compact metric spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let X and Y be compact metric spaces. Is the set of surjective isometries of X to Y compact with respect to the topology of uniform convergence?

The answer is positive if X=Y as you can see in

[Compact metric space group $Iso(X,d)$ is also compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398511/compact-metric-space-group-isox-d-is-also-compact?rq=1)

Is it true if Y is distinct from X?

Comment: If there is an isometry between $X$ and $Y$, how are they different?

Comment: Any isomorphism (i.e., surjective isometry) $\phi : X \to Y$, induces a bijection between the isomorphisms of $X \to Y$ and the isomorphisms $X \to X$ by $\alpha \mapsto \phi^{-1} \circ \alpha$. This bijection is easily seen to be an isomorphism of $\text{Iso}(X,Y)$ and $\text{Iso}(X)$. In particular, it is a homeomorphism, so if one is compact, the other is as well.